# maestro detalle delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi-tokyo, fastreport

Buenas noches gente PROGRAMO EN DELPHI, tengo dos tablas llamadas 1_productos y 2_detalle_productos, mi problema es el siguiente cuando quiera que me muestre los productos con sus respetivos detalles solo me muestran los productos que tienen asignados los detalles, yo necesitaría que me haga una muestra general
las consulta las hago desde dos FDquery

P/D Mi problema es que como selecciono una fecha desde hasta solo me muestra los productos que tiene detalles asignados de la tabla y yo necesito que me muestro todos los productos tengan o no detalle.

espero haberme hecho entender

Comment: Necesitamos ver lo que has intentado para poderte ayudar. No veo código en tu pregunta ni errores, tan solo una exposición y las respuestas no pueden ser demasaido atinadas de esta forma.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo lógico en estos casos es utilizar una `SELECT` que una ambas tablas para mostrar productos y sus detalles; Algo como esto:

```
SELECT P.*, D.* FROM PRODUCTOS P 
INNER JOIN DETALLE D ON D.IDPRODUCTO=PRODUCTO.ID
```

Como ves en este ejemplo se usa `INNER JOIN` para "unir" los datos de ambas tablas. `INNER JOIN` se comporta tal y como tú comentas, sólo mostrará datos si existen registros en ambas tablas relacionados. Si no hay detalle para un determinado producto ese producto no aparecerá.

En el caso de que existan productos sin detalle (que parece que es el tuyo), debes usar `LEFT JOIN` o `RIGHT JOIN`.

Si la misma consulta la haces con un `LEFT JOIN`, aparecerán TODOS los productos, aunque no tengan detalle.

```
SELECT P.*, D.* FROM PRODUCTOS P 
LEFT JOIN DETALLE D ON D.IDPRODUCTO=PRODUCTO.ID
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias German pero no me sirvio sigo sin poder visualizar los datos del maestro.

Comment: Pero "no visualizas los datos del maestro" ¿por error en la consulta SQL? ¿Por algún otro problema?
Te asegueo que la LEFT JOIN funciona como te comento y "DEBEN" aparecer los datos de la tabla principal si lo usas correctamente.

Comment: La consulta en el FDQUERY esta barbaro funciona de maravilla,  donde no me funciona es en la banda del fastreport, tengo un banda maestro y otro detalle, en la banda maestro esta relacionacion  a los datos de la tabla TURNOS y en la banda detalle esta relacionado a la datos de PAGOS